# High load on jetty

Tags: jetty, load-testing

I'm running load tests on my MBP. The load is injected using gatling.

My web server is jetty 9.2.6

On a heavy load, number of threads remains constant : 300 but the number open socket is growing from 0 to 4000+, which generates a too much open files at OS level.

What does it mean ?
Any idea to improve the situation ?

Here is the output of jetty stat

`Statistics:
Statistics gathering started 643791ms ago
Requests:
Total requests: 56084
Active requests: 1
Max active requests: 195
Total requests time: 36775697
Mean request time: 655.7369791202325
Max request time: 12638
Request time standard deviation: 1028.5144674112403
Dispatches:
Total dispatched: 56084
Active dispatched: 1
Max active dispatched: 195
Total dispatched time: 36775697
Mean dispatched time: 655.7369791202325
Max dispatched time: 12638
Dispatched time standard deviation: 1028.5144648655212
Total requests suspended: 0
Total requests expired: 0
Total requests resumed: 0
Responses:
1xx responses: 0
2xx responses: 55644
3xx responses: 0
4xx responses: 0
5xx responses: 439
Bytes sent total: 281222714
Connections:
org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector@243883582
Protocols:http/1.1 
Statistics gathering started 643784ms ago
Total connections: 8788
Current connections open: 1
Max concurrent connections open: 4847
Mean connection duration: 77316.87629452601
Max connection duration: 152694
Connection duration standard deviation: 36153.705226514794
Total messages in: 56083
Total messages out: 56083
Memory:
Heap memory usage: 1317618808 bytes
Non-heap memory usage: 127525912 bytes`

Comment: how many worker threads have you configured? This just means that you might be falling short of jetty worker thread and you are synchronously processing the request and its taking long while the socket is open. You should look for processing events asyncly.

Comment: default values, no custom config of the thread pool

Comment: `Max concurrent connections open: 4847 Mean connection duration: 77316.87629452601` see this you have 4.8K concurrent connections and you are taking 77K seconds to process each events. is that really true?

Comment: no, I inject 20.000 users during 10 min, at 200 req/s. But I don't know why connections remains open…

Comment: What is the state of those open sockets?  Are they TIME_WAIT or CLOSE_WAIT?

Comment: There are all ESTABLISHED. With Gatling, each virtual user make a connection but I don't understand why there are not closed when the user has finished to send request.

Answer (score 3):

Some advice:

- Don't have the Client Load and the Server Load on the same machine (don't cheat and attempt to put the load on 2 different VMs on a single physical machine)
- Use multiple client machines, not just 1 (when the Jetty developers test load characteristics, we use at least 10:1 ratio of client machines to server machines)
- Don't test with loopback, virtual network interfaces, localhost, etc..  Use a real network interface.
- Understand how your load client manages its HTTP version + connections (such as keep-alive or http/1.1 close), and make sure you read the response body content, close the response content / streams, and finally disconnect the connection.
- Don't test with unrealistic load scenarios.  A real-world usage of your server will be a majority of HTTP/1.1 pipelined connections with multiple requests per physical connection.  Some on fast networks, some on slow networks, some even on unreliable networks (think mobile)
- Raw speed, serving the same content, all on unique connections, is ultimately a fascinating number [and can produce impressive results](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r8&hw=i7&test=plaintext), and also completely pointless and proves nothing about how your application's performance on Jetty will behave with real world scenarios.

Finally, [be sure you are testing load in realistic ways](https://webtide.com/lies-damned-lies-and-benchmarks-2/).

Comment: I've came here from `CLOSE_WAIT` search page in Google while doing some load tests, and this is a brilliant answer!